# Regex - matching only digits, excluding special characters - doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying out reggae and was trying to remove the special characters like parentheses, brackets etc. from a phone number. Instead of getting the first 3 digits (which I intended), I am getting this [ '201', index: 0, input: '2014447777' ]
Why is this happening?

```
 function numbers(num){
 return num.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").match(/\d\d\d/);

}
numbers("(347)4448888");
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: the expected output is just 347 (not as a string)

Answer (score 3):

[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value) returns

> An Array containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results, or null if there were no matches.

To get first three digits, use

```
return num.replace(/\D+/g, '').match(/\d{3}/)[0];
                    ^^^               ^^^^^  ^^^   : Match all non-digits
                                      ^^^^^  ^^^   : Match three digits and returns digits from the array.
```

Comment: Thanks. But why am I getting the array anyway?

Comment: Also, can you explain what you mean by "null if there were no matches" because that happened to me when  was looking for 1 letter and in case that there wasn't a letter it didn't return 0 but null and I don't understand why

Comment: @learningcoding `match` returns array of matches as you've added in question. To use default, use `return num.replace(/\D+/g, '').match(/\d{3}/)[0] || 0;`